# Sparse Matrix Function

Tags: c

This is my homework. I can return void, but I don't know how to use `int` and how to examine when something goes wrong and returns `-1;`

￼ADT SMatrix is:

1. Heading

   Sparse Matrix (with dimension rows x cols) of integers.

Functions:

```
int SMTX_read (SMatrixType A)

::= read in a matrix from stdin and stores the matrix in A.
::= returns SMTX_ERROR if something went wrong
--------/* For this project, the input format will be
Line 1: two integers, rows & cols, dimension of the matrix Line 2 to rows+1: contains cols number of integers
Should take the input and convert to your proper ADT format */


int SMTX_print(SMatrixType A)

::= print the sparse matrix A in the following format
/* Line 1: print “Rows = ??, Cols = ??, # of non-zero entries = ??” Line 2 ~ ??: print “< Ri, Ci, entry-value>,” one 3-tuple per line */



int SMTX_add (SMatrixType A, B, C)

::= C <= A + B
::= returns SMTX_ERROR if something went wrong

int SMTX_subtract (SMatrixType A, B, C)

::= C <= A - B
::= returns SMTX_ERROR if something went wrong

int SMTX_transpose (SMatrixType A, B) ::= B <= AT

::= returns SMTX_ERROR if something went wrong

int SMTX_multiply (SMatrixType A, B, C)



 ::= C <= A x B
    ::= returns SMTX_ERROR if something went wrong /* please use the quick 

algorithm given in lecture */
```

Data typing:

```
define SMTX_ERROR -1
define MAX_SMTX_SIZE 100
typedef struct SMatrix {
. ..
} SMatrixType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error handling is intended to be performed via return values. Void could be for instance the print function when expecting no errors at all. Reading function and other operations should check the input: e. g. matrices are of according dimensions, or other problems may arise and outcome will not match expectations.

```
int SMTX_read (SMatrixType A)
{
    int err = 0;
    /* reading input */
    if( outcome != expected ) { err = SMTX_ERROR; }
    /* .. */
    return err;
}
```

Or an other example:

```
int division( int dividend, int divisor, int * quotient_ptr )
{
    int err = -1;
    if( 0 != divisor ) { err = 0; *quotient_ptr = dividend / divisor; }
    return err;
}
```